# How to print field values horizontally in a table in JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using **Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1.final** to design a report with a table among other elements.

The design looks like below. The table only has a **Column Header** and a **Detail** section.

[image]

Now the fields are printed vertically like this:

```
COLUMN_HEADER1  |  COLUMN_HEADER2
col1Val1        |  ...
col1Val2        |  ...
col1Val3        |  ...
```

But what I need is to display them horizontally like this:

```
COLUMN_HEADER1    |   col1Val1   |     col1Val2     |      col1Val3
COLUMN_HEADER2    |   ...        |     ...          |      ...
```

I searched the net and couldn't get any luck.

Is there a way to do that? I am stuck in here. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

That's how I pass in the data to the report (using existing Java service to generate a JRBeanCollectionDataSource).

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> aListOfMap = ...;
    JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(aListOfMap);
    HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("DataSource", jrDataSource);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = getObjectPdf("reports/report.jrxml", parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Comment: How do you retrieve data for this report?

Comment: Hi @Viki888, I am using existing Java service to generate a JRBeanCollectionDataSource. Please see my inline edits. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of requirement either need to be **achieved while data retrieval** or using `crosstab` component.

You can refer link [working with crosstabs in Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v621/working-crosstabs) for crosstab sample design.

Also refer the link [Working with Tables and CrossTabs in JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/tables-and-crosstabs-jaspersoft-studio) to know how table and crosstab differ in their functionality.

If you want to achieve this in `table`, then you have to apply `pivoting` in your data retrieval process.

Comment: Thanks you. Finally I used a list to achieve this, which I fed with a list of objects.